# Why is it easier to drop on to a downslope?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, free-fall

On a bicycle, why is it easier to land from a drop or jump on a slope going downwards than landing on a flat surface or on an upslope?

I've already heard answers such as "because that's how a bike can best keep going with all the momentum it's carrying from the drop" but I'm asking for a more elaborate answer that can give a good understanding of the physics involved.

Comment: The physics you're referring to aren't specific to bicycles, they apply to virtually any moving object.

Comment: because the change in direction is smaller.

Comment: Since you want "a good understanding of the physics", this might be a better question for the physics stack exchange site, especially if you want the math behind the explanation. Do you want us to migrate it there for you?

Comment: @freiheight yeah sounds like a good idea

Answer (score 4):

When you're landing from a jump, you're moving in a forward and downward direction. Landing on a downward slope simply eases the transition as this is already your direction of momentum. A flat or uphill slope will rapidly change your momentum to match the surface.

Comment: Agreed - the extreme case is landing on something that is 90 degrees from your path of travel.  That's bad for your forward momentum, more-so if its relatively immoveable and incompressible.

Would you rather land *on* a concrete road or *into*  a concrete wall?

Comment: This is the correct answer. The only thing [physics.se] would add is the math.

Comment: and ain't no one got time for math!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will satisfy more:
When you imagine a body (or a bike) think of the velocity vector in space, that vector upon impact will cause a reaction in the direction of the normal vector of the surface you are falling uppon:

[image: blue vector = speed, orange = surface normal, black = normal x and y compositions]
[image]

As you can see, the upwards reaction from the surface on the velocity vector will be multiplied by cos(Θ) where Θ is the angle between the surface normal and the velocity vector.

When the angle between the direction you are falling and the slope is nearly 0, your speed is barely absorbed.

Comment: Both of your diagrams are down-slopes. OP asks about landing on an up-slope.

Comment: The effects for upslope, downslope, sideslope are the same, it depends on the angle of the speed vector and normal vector only. if you do it in 0g it's also the same.. Except you won't start accelerating again.